# How to add video file on ajax put method using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, video

I am using laravel 5.4 ..In my edit page need to add one video am using ajax function to pass the data to controller everthing works fine but my video didnot added properly...

```
$('#updateProduct').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(e);
    var redirect_url = $(this).find("[name='redirect_url']").val();
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var method = $(this).attr('method');
    var video = document.getElementById('videoToUpload').files[0];
    console.log(video);
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("videos", video);
    formData.append('name', $(this).find("[name='name']").val());
    formData.append('description', $(this).find("[name='description']").val());
    console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({
        type: "PATCH",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
          //window.location.href = redirect_url;
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
          console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
        }
      });

  });
```

This is my ajax function

And my laravel view is

```
<form data-toggle="validator" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('products.update', $pid) }}" method="put" id="updateProduct" class="bc-from-myfroup">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <input value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" name="seller_id" type="hidden">
                <input value="{{ route('user.products') }}" name="redirect_url" type="hidden">
                <div id="setdetails">
                  <div class="bc-my-from">Edit Product</div>
                  <div class="form-group bc-my-group">
                    <label>Item Name *</label>
                    <input class="form-control bc-form-elem-sign" value="{{ $product->name }}" name="name" type="text" required data-error="Please enter Item Name"> 
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group bc-my-group">
                    <label>Description</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control bc-form-elem-sign" name="description" type="text">{{ $product->description }}</textarea>
                  </div>
<div class="form-group bc-my-group">
                    <label>Video Upload</label>
                    <div class="input-group image-preview">
                      <input id="videoToUpload" class="form-control image-preview-filename" type="file" accept="video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*" name="video"/>
                    </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

And this is my controller

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
         if (Input::hasFile('videos'))
         {

            return Response::json([
                'message' => 'fd1',
        ], 200);
        }
    }
```

Here i just checked when i choose video and click submit button it goes or not....But that message is not displayed...I think the problem occured because of this method can any one help me out how to i add video inside ajax put method